# Python method/function chaining

Tags: python, chaining

In python, is it possible to chain together class methods and functions together? For example, if I want to instantiate a class object and call a method on it that affects an instance variable's state, could I do that? Here is an example:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'Hello'

    @classmethod
    def make_upper(y):
        y.x = y.x.upper()
```

What I'm wanting to do is this:

`h = Test().make_upper()`

I want to instantiate a class object and affect the state of a variable in one line of code, but I would also like to be able to chain together multiple functions that can affect state or do something else on the object. Is this possible in python like it is in jQuery?

Comment: If each method you call returns the object that provides the next method you want to call, it will work. If they don't, it won't. It depends how your methods are written.

Comment: If all your methods return self, sure

Comment: Generally not good design, but if it works for you, it works for you.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want make_upper to be a classmethod.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, sure. Just return `self` from the instance methods you are interested in:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'Hello'

    def make_upper(self):
        self.x = self.x.upper()
        return self
    def make_lower(self):
        self.x = self.x.lower()
        return self

h = Test().make_upper()
print(h.x)
```

Output:

```
HELLO
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. The chaining certainly works, but `h` is the return value of `make_upper()`, not the object returned by `Test()`. You need to write this as two lines.

```
h = Test()
h.make_upper()
```

---

*However*, [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) was recently accepted for inclusion in Python 3.8, which means someday you could write

```
(h := Test()).make_upper()
```

The return value of `Test()` is assigned to `h` in the current scope *and* used as the value of the `:=` expression, which then invokes its `make_upper` method. I'm not sure I would recommend using `:=` in this case, though; the currently required syntax is much more readable.