# Why is an object not created when a method is called during the object's contruction?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object

Given the class `test`, why it is not possible to instantiate it by calling one of its methods along with the constructor?

```py
class test:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def print_a(self):
        print(self.a)
```

Here is an example:

```py
>>> obj = test("Hello").print_a()  # Prints the desired output.
Hello
>>> obj
>>> print(obj)  # But the object does not exist.
None
>>> obj = test("Hello")  # It obviously works when doing it separately. 
>>> obj
<__main__.test object at 0x7f537fea3940>
>>> obj.print_a()
Hello
```

Why is it not possible to chain a method call with the constructor call?

This was implemented in `python3`.

Comment: `obj` is the return value of `print_a` which has no `return` statement, so it returns `None`.

Comment: In `obj = test("Hello").print_a()`, obj is set to the result of print which is None.  Meaning method print_a returns None.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176274/python-method-function-chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning obj to the return value of the function *print_a* (which is None as it has no return). The actual test object was never stored and is therefore no longer in scope when you try to print it.